# protobuf maven 3 protoc plugin error

Tags: java, maven-3, protocol-buffers

in my pom.xml I have following google protobuf plugin declaration:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <protocExecutable>protoc</protocExecutable>
                <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/protobuf/</protoSourceRoot>
                <languageSpecifications>
                    <LanguageSpecification>
                        <language>JAVA</language>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    </LanguageSpecification>
                </languageSpecifications>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

but my eclipse shows following error:

```
protoc did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information. (com.google.protobuf.tools:maven-protoc-plugin:0.3.1:compile:default:generate-sources)
```

How to solve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your project as "Maven install", for example. Then check console output. In my case, this was simple:

```
/bin/sh: protoc: command not found.
```

This means that eclipse cant find protoc. You should add path to protoc to PATH variable. On Mac, I added path to protoc to /etc/launchd.conf.
Or you can install [protoclipse](https://code.google.com/p/protoclipse/) and set path in Eclipse Preferences.